# Unexplainable error while parsing JSON

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, asihttprequest

I'm trying to parse JSON into NSDictionary. I have tried a lot of different ways and i always have the same error. Here's the simplest example:

```
     NSString *response = [request responseString];
     NSLog(@"%@",response);

     NSDictionary *jsonDict = [response JSONValue];
     NSLog(@"%@",jsonDict);
```

I can have two types of responseString: 
1)something like `{"s_login":{"error":6}}`

and

2) something like `{s_login:{"error":0,"sid":"66d4da3e870427bb"}}`

So the problem is:

When responseString is 1 - everything is OK. I'm able to make it into NSDictionary and my NSLog tells me:

```
{
"s_login" =     {
    error = 6;
};
}
```

but when responseString is the second variant, then NSDictionary is null and this is what i'm having in console output:

```
 -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
"Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Object key string expected\" UserInfo=0x6043680 {NSLocalizedDescription=Object key string expected}"
```

Seems like i've described my issue fully. Any help is highly desired and appreciated. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response:

```
{s_login:{"error":0,"sid":"66d4da3e870427bb"}}
```

is not a valid JSON string. It's missing the double quotes around `s_login`. They are mandatory.

You'll have to fix it on the server side.

Answer (score 4):

```
{s_login:{"error":0,"sid":"66d4da3e870427bb"}}
```

Should be

```
{"s_login":{"error":0,"sid":"66d4da3e870427bb"}}
```